# How to add default namespaces to Web Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, web-config

I read an article [here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/2287.aspx) to find the solution to my problem. But I found that it is not working for me. Whenever I tries to use any function I have to add same namespace on every page. by doing `using System.Web.UI` . Can I also use it for namespace that is being created along with an application. i.e. Library is an another namespace that lies in App_Code folder not as an assembly.

```
<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Library.ExceptionHandler"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
      </namespaces>
</pages>
```

**Is there any way to get them available at Code Behind Page**

Comment: the namespaces that you have added to the config only effect the aspx markup files. @pranay is correct in suggesting those links, particularly the second one.

Answer (score 1):

yes but you have to change the default C# class template for that check following article

[Changing the default using directives in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/steve/changing-the-default-using-directives-in-visual-studio)

also check this

[Does C# Support Project-Wide Default Namespace Imports Like VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789239/does-c-support-project-wide-default-namespace-imports-like-vb-net)