# How to set type alias for whole namespace scope in c#

Tags: c#, namespaces, alias

I want to use an alias for a data type by doing this:

```
using MyGUID = System.GUID;
```

How can I make the scope of this namespace-wide without having to add that line to every  class in my project?

Comment: Looks like the answer is that you cant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789239/does-c-sharp-support-project-wide-default-namespace-imports-like-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Instead, create an extension method(s) which encapsulates the operation(s) which you want to encompass using `System.Guid`. If the extension(s) is in a base namespace used throughout the project one would not have to include it throughout and access it easily as per the target classes.