# Import a namespace for a whole project

Tags: import, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, using

I would like to replace some functionalities in several classes of an existing project. Is it possible to use the keyword Imports (or Using in c#) globally for a project?

Meaning for example i would like to specify "Imports System.Math" somewhere in my project settings and would expect this namespace to be available in all classes of my project afterwards.

If this is not possible, can i somewhere set default imports to automatically add "Imports System.Math" to any class which i create from now on?

Comment: This is possible using VB.NET.  Project-level imports are possible with VB.NET.  However, I don't think it's possible with a C# project.

Comment: I'm afraid this is also a duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789239/does-c-sharp-support-project-wide-default-namespace-imports-like-vb-net

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this was exactly the information that i was looking for.