# Referencing namespaces globally?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Is there a way to reference a namespace globally across the whole solution?

So instead of having these lines in every code file:

```
using System;
using MyNamespace;
```

having to declare them only once, and every code file would use them.

Btw I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: In C# 10 and above, you can use `global using`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, C# doesn't have this concept. Each source file is independent in this respect. (And if the using directives are in a namespace declaration, those are independent from other using directives in peer namespace declarations, too. That's a pretty rare case though in my experience.)

You don't need ReSharper to change what gets included in a new class though. You can use the [Visual Studio templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651055/default-using-directives-in-new-c-files).

EDIT: Just to clarify the point about using directives within namespaces, suppose we had (all in one file):

```
using Foo;

namespace X
{
    using Bar;
    // Foo and Bar are searched for code in here, but not Baz
}

namespace Y
{
    using Baz;
    // Foo and Baz are searched for code in here, but not Bar
}
```

Usually I only have one namespace declaration in a file, and put all the using directives before it.

Comment: You're amazing. Every time I see (or post) an answer that looks complete and final to me, you come up with something better :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. In your 3rd sentence do you mean, if you have namespace declaration inside another namespace (CustomNS), and if you use the CustomNS, those namespaces wouldn't be included for a file that uses that namespace?

Comment: Thanks Jon. What about adding "using X;" inside namespace Y? I actually tried but it didn't give me access to what's inside Bar (which is included in X).

Comment: No, it wouldn't. A using directive only affects the look-up for source code within that namespace declaration (or the whole file if it's at the top). It doesn't embed that lookup into the generated code or anything like that.

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated now, as others have pointed out there is now a notion of a project-wide `global using ns` that at least partially achieve what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible.

If you're using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html), you can set an option to include specific using directives in every new file you create though.

Answer (score 3):

In `C# 10.0` you can use [Global Usings](https://exceptionnotfound.net/bite-size-csharp-10-global-usings/).

```
global using System;
global using MyNamespace;
```

Comment: That feature is still "in preview" as of 09/06/2021

Answer (score 2):

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700086/how-do-you-default-a-new-class-to-public-when-creating-it-in-visual-studio) and follow-up [blog post](http://guyellisrocks.com/coding/defaulting-a-class-to-public-from-visual-studio/). You can edit the Visual Studio default templates.

To do this, look at the file in this zip : [Program Files][Visual Studio]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

and modify the Class.cs file as needed. Additionally, Visual Studio may have cached this file here :
[Program Files][Visual Studio]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not reference a namespace globally across the whole solution in .NET or .NET CORE.

But you can use project wise namespace globally in solution. this feature will be available from `c#10/.NET 6`. currently it's in preview but it will be released in **NOV 2021**

=========Project level .NET 6 global using namespace=========

Create a class file at root of the project e.g `GlobalNamespace.cs`

```
global using System;
global using System.Linq;
global using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
global using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Then you don't need to declare `using namespace` in other `.cs` files of the project  which are already declared globally.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned Visual Studio Templates are the way to go.

Note that simply adding a using statement to your template will not ensure that the compiler can resolve your types.  So, if you are adding a using statement for MyNamespace in every class you may need to add an assembly reference to your project as well.  See the [C# FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/04/29/123028.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score -3):

One trick I miss as a newb to CSharp is to look at the "refences" (in VS), to right click and "Add New Reference". This is especially handy when combining mulitple projects where I have made some generic class for reuse elsewhere.