# Stop Visual Studio 2005 adding references to System.Data and System.XML

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Does anyone know how I can stop Visual Studio 2005 adding references to the System.Data and System.XML assemblies every time I add a class to a c# project?
It does not use any of them and I need to remove them everytime I notice.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean namespaces or assemblies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Class template contains such. To edit it, open:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
\Class.vstemplate
```

and remove unnecessary references.

To remove unnecessary namespaces, edit:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
\Class.cs
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that answer to this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-class-interface

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this just be a case of altering the .cs template in Visual Studio and deleting the using statements you don't require? See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit vstemplage file

I think this is the same topic  here  [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-class-interface)