# What other variables are available in visual studio template files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, visual-studio-2012

I've just stumbled upon another question while researching my ability to implement modifications to the Visual Studio 'Class Template File' ( as I'll call it... ); which can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745688/how-can-i-change-the-default-visual-studio-c-sharp-new-class-file-template) and subsequently [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface/2072717#2072717).

Now, there were a couple of very helpful answers there but there doesn't seem to be any further information on what other variables might be available in this context.

It seems that there are at least 3 variabels; TargetFrameworkVersion, RootNameSpace, and SafeItemRootName ( At least in 2012 ), but I am curious if anyone has any idea as to what else might be available in this context.

Answer (score 1):

A list of parameters available in visual studio template files can be found at MSDN at the following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx

Comment: that document doesn't for example list safeitemrootname, referred to by the OP, and used in the Class.cs template file.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 - R u sure that link mentioned in your answer contains all the template parameters?