# Why does Visual Studio scaffold Web Api Controllers to inherit Controller as opposed to ControllerBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am expecting that a new controller for a Web Api (ie- no UI, no views etc), would be created by VS2017 to inherit from

> AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase   *(in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll)*

instead of from:

> AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller  *(which is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll - and contains view support)*

Example controller generated by VS:

```
namespace WebApi1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {   
        // ....
```

Can someone help me understand if I'm missing something here?

If not, does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent use of Controller in a WebApi only project?

*I had thought of a hacky method of implementing a base class in my WebApi1.Controllers namespace called Controller that effectively intercepts a WebApi controller that uses Controller over ControllerBase, but perhaps a filter might be better?*

Comment: I assume you mean when you create a new controller using the VS wizard? Why can't you just change the code to use `ControllerBase`?

Comment: Well yes I can and usually would remember to, will all other developers?  Will I always remember? ...

Comment: I hope this helps  [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4785)

Comment: I'd imagine it's just an oversight in the VS deploy since the .NET core stuff is moving quite quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745688/how-can-i-change-the-default-visual-studio-c-sharp-new-class-file-template - I'd just edit your templates for now and maybe raise the issue on the GH repo

Comment: Thanks @Charleh & @chiragMM - for now I will add this class in my controller's namespace with suitable comment, which should cause a compiler error for scaffolded types: `internal abstract class Controller { Controller() { } }`