# Can I change the content of default files in a Visual Studio project type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-project

In Visual Studio 2019, when I create a new .NET Framework Console Application in C#, it places the entry point in a class called `Program` in a file named `Program.cs` and a namespace with the same name as my project:

```
namespace ProjectName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I always just end up removing the namespace and renaming the class and file to `EntryPoint`(`.cs`), putting the entry point class in the global namespace.

```
sealed class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make this the default behavior for all new projects of this type from now on without manually doing that each time? In other words, can I change how the default files in this type of project look?

Comment: You can create custom [`dotnet new` template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) (so you don't need to mess with the default ones).

Comment: would it be better to have to have the entry class `EntryPoint` as `static` instead of `sealed`.

Comment: @GuruStron Good to know, but the solution from the accepted answer is simpler. :-)

Comment: @GovindParmar it depends. With the templates you can share  this with your team via nuget,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be helpful
[How can I change the default Visual Studio C# new class file template? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745688/how-can-i-change-the-default-visual-studio-c-sharp-new-class-file-template)

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019#installed-templates):

> By default, templates installed with Visual Studio are located in:
>
> - %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\[edition]\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\[Language]\[Locale ID]

For example on my machine - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates`