# How to add #region when Implementation Interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017. How can I achieve it?

```
   public class Test : IFace
{
    #region IFace implementation
```

**How can I add this #region when Auto-Generate?**

```
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //TODO...
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567594/automatically-add-regions-to-code-in-visual-studio

Comment: Auto generate what?

Comment: I think OP means when you write `public class Test: IFace` and then right-click `IFace` and select "Quick Actions and Refactorings > Implement Interface". That threw me too for a moment.

Comment: Yes,that's what i mean. "Quick Actions and Refactorings > Implement Interface" . Generate #region ..........  #endregion.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551803/automatically-surround-generated-code-with-region-when-implementing-interfaces
Looks like this particular option that enables you to achieve exactly what you want, was present as far as I remember in VS 2012 but it's gone since VS 2015 and, unfortunately, they haven't fixed it to this day.