# Visual D code template

Tags: d

Visual D code template looks like this:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;

int main(string[] argv)
{
   writeln("Hello D-World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to change the template into:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;

void main() {

}
```

Comment: I don't have visual D installed, but I'm assuming it uses the same path as all the other templates. In that case, this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface

Answer (score 1):

You can change the templates in the VisualD installation folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualD\Templates\
```

I changed the file below and the new Console App Project template reflected the change.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualD\Templates\ProjectItems\ConsoleApp\main.d
```