# How do I automatically add namespace in aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, resharper

I am doing refactoring and I need to add in almost all aspx and ascx files

I will add this import if I have some variables defined in that file (var1 or var2 or var3).

Is it possible to do this automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is no way of project wide importing. You will have to manually import in every file.This functionality is available in vb.net though.

However if you are gonna use the import in all classes you can edit the template. Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)