# How to change default #includes in Visual Studio 2013(C++) when I create a new project?

Tags: c++, ide, include

Everytime I create a new project in Visual Studio, by default it includes stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp However, I would also like to include string,vector,iostream by default as well, where in the options can I change these settings to include these libraries as well every time I make a new project?

Comment: This may have been answered [over here][1]. Please tell us if it works for C++.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you want, but you can put all those includes into stdafx.h each time you start a project. That has the same effect as putting the includes in every cpp file.