# How to edit C# class template in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to edit the C# template so that I don't have to keep adding directives that I commonly use.

After googling a little there is mention of finding the template in some zip file however this is for VS versions prior to 2013.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface