# Resharper: File header text not automatically used for new files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, stylecop

I am using VS2010, Resharper 8.0.1, StyleCop 4.7.45.

I have defined a File header text in the resharper options and (wrongly) assumed it would then be used when refactoring (using "move class to a new file to match file name" function). This also doesnt use the Visual Studio file templates that one may modify (see [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)).

Is there a way to enable that behaviour, or do I always have to manually trigger Code cleanup afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in Resharper as of now. Your current solution to run Code Cleanup is the way to go.

Related:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329925

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-170107

It's been an issue / feature request reported back since at least 2010.