# How to define ReSharper file header for .cshtml files and .js files?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

For .cs source files it is possible to define standard file header in ReSharper what is automatically inserted/updated when code cleanup is called.

Is it possible to define similar for .cshtml and .js files?

Answer (score 0):

answered over here: 
[Resharper: File header text not automatically used for new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839810/resharper-file-header-text-not-automatically-used-for-new-files)

> ...isn't possible in Resharper
>
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329925
>
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-170107