# Custom Formated Class.cs File - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, format

Now I structure my C# class files in regions:

**

1. Property region
2. Field region
3. Constructor region
4. Method region

**

Is there anyway to create a custom Class template which includes my regions (and another formatting) automatically when I press **Add New Item -> Class...** so I can save time?

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: I think I may need a T4 Template? 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the Visual Studio C# class template:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$
using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
    {
        #region Properties
        #endregion Properties
        #region Fields
        #endregion Fields
        #region Constructors
        #endregion Constructors
        #region Methods
        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

You can see the location of them in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072717/3515415) answer.