# Setup New File Default Text

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How can I setup Visual Studio 2013 to populate new C++ header and cpp files with default text?

I know I could create a custom snippet and then press the keys to insert it but it would be nice to have this automatically inserted when the new file is created.

Eg; insert the following into new .h files:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_NAME_FILE_NAME_H
#define PROJECT_NAME_FILE_NAME_H

class FileName
{
public:
    // Static Variables //

    // Static Methods //

    // Class Variables //

    // Class Methods //

protected:
    // Static Variables //

    // Static Methods //

    // Class Variables //

    // Class Methods //

private:
    // Static Variables //

    // Static Methods //

    // Class Variables //

    // Class Methods //

};

#endif // PROJECT_NAME_FILE_NAME_H
```

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may update the default models provided by MSCV.

I have no longer MSVC2013 installed but for MSVC2015 they are in directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojectitems` :  `hfile.h` for the headers, and `newc++file.cpp` for cpp files.

Attention:  to edit these files, you need to run your editor with administrator priviledge.

Another approach could be to create your own item templates.  This is pretty easy:  you start a project, add a `.cpp` or a `.h`, change it with the content you want to be used. Then export it (File->export template...).  Here there is a [step by step approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx).  You must make sure that at the end, the generated `.zip` file is copied in your user's directory to the folder `Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates` in the existing C++ subfolder.

**Important notice:** new templates might be taken into account at startup of MSVC only.  SO be sure you exit and enter again MSVC to see the new templates added.

***Edit following additional question in comments***

In your templates you can use [template parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx), that will be automatically replaced when the item is added to a project (provided `ReplaceParameters="true"` in the `.vstemplate` file of the exported template).

Example: a header template designed to ensure an include guard:

```
// $itemname$.h
// by $username$

#ifndef $safeitemname$_H
#define $safeitemname$_H

// TO DO: your guarded header here

#endif
```

When adding a new element using this header template, the paramter substitution will result in:

```
// my_funny_header.h
// by Christophe

#ifndef my_funny_header_H
#define my_funny_header_H

// TO DO: your guarded header here

#endif
```

Note however, that not all the paramters can be used. For example $projectname$ works only for project templates, not for itemtemplates. Note also that `$safeitemname$` should be preferred to `$itemname$` in symbol definition.

Comment: thanks. The path on VS2013 is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcprojectitems`. Have you been able to use VS macros in these files? For eg `#ifndef $(ProjectName)_$(TargetName)_H`. Currently these are not being converted when the header file is created.

Comment: @JakeM Fine ! Yes you can use template parameters, but with some limitations.  See my edit.