# How can I cause visual studio to automatically include a using statement like using System.Diagnostics, in every project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I cause visual studio to automatically include a using statement like using System.Diagnostics, in every project?

I've been developing winforms applications and console applications and would like System.Diagnostics to be imported automatically with a using statement so I don't have to manually put the using statement in.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit this file:

```
(YourDriveNameHere):\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
                         Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class/Class.cs
```

To be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit an appropriate class template for the Visual Studio so each new generated class will have `using` statements that you have put there.

For how to do this, check this question: [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can do this the way @[user3185569](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185569/user3185569) told.

Also, there is a file named **Class.vstemplate** in that same directory. Open it and you can easily edit the following:

```
<TemplateContent>
        <References>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System</Assembly>
            </Reference>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System.Diagnostics</Assembly>
            </Reference>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System.Web</Assembly>
            </Reference>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System.Data</Assembly>
            </Reference>
        </References>

    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>
```