# using system.linq for each new project created?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want my Visual Studio to generate libraries such:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

each time I create a new project or solution. Is that possible?

Comment: Edit your project templates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294114/how-can-i-cause-visual-studio-to-automatically-include-a-using-statement-like-us

Comment: You don't need to "generate libraries", you want to use "global usings" - which is possible in the newest templates

Comment: "each time i create a new project or solution." actually I am a little confused. because `using System.Collections.Generic;` would be something you would put into a *.cs file when you create a class for example. This is not the level of projects or even solutions. What exactly are you talking about. please describe the steps you want to take and the precise result you expect to find

Comment: its like - im tired to write "using system..." every time i create a new solution or a new project. i want to automate this. Im using those libraries in almost each project i create

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C# 10+ (default with .NET 6+), you can enable `ImplicitUsings` in your project file. There are a handful of common namespaces (including the two you mention) that are then automatically imported for all your code files. More info here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/#global-and-implicit-usings

Your `.csproj` file might look like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you explane step by step how to do so? Its buch of unclear text in the link you've sent :(