# How to auto-add project details to main program code in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I want Visual Studio to automatically add project details like: author, date and time when project was created into comment on top of the main code between 'using' stuff and 'namespace'. I looked hard for this but i didn't find anything intresting. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. When i do changes to Class.cs file it doesn't appear in VS. Thanks for any help :)

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Text; //And so on

/*There i want my details
  Author: Matias
  Date: 11.03.2018 - 2am
*/

namespace MyNamespace
//Code below
```

I want to get this added automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)

Comment: @john Changes doesn't appear in VS and i don't have ItemTemplatesCache folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, got solution! I just had to type

```
/**
* Author: $username$
* Date: $time$
*/
```

in my code and then export the template by Project -> Export template