# Removing Visual Basic project Templates from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to remove the Visual Studio project templates from showing up in Visual Studio 2019? I'm never going to use them and I've had multiple occurences where I accidentially created a new Visual Basic project instead of a C# project.

[image]

I've tried removing the physical files from `Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates` and clearing the cache but the project templates keep showing up in the dialog.

Comment: That's what the dropdown filters are for, is it not?

Comment: It's great for filtering, true. But I'm literally never going to use VB, so being able to remove them completely would be even nicer

Comment: As far as I know the location you listed is the only location that VS knows to look for them. Did you restart your machine after deleting them to see if that cleared them from the list? Or did an update to VS 2019 perhaps re-add them?

Comment: It's about ItemTemplates, not ProjectTemplates, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface#comment2003353_2072717) may prove useful/relevant; not sure how much crossover there is between the implementation of ProjectTemplate files vs ItemTemplate files (tl;dr there are some additional things to remove to really get them out of VS).

Answer (score 1):

to remove a template from Visual Studio you may use:

```
dotnet new --uninstall NAMEOFTEMPLATE.Template
```

to uninstall some project types (Visual Basic maybe) try Change Visual Studio Tool from Setup...