# 'using' directives be inside the namespace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, using, using-directives

I am trying to make custom template project in Visual Studio 2019. In my template Project directives ***should*** be inside the namespace.
while coding I am keeping them inside. But when project generated I see them outside(my code is overwritten).

How can I make Visual Studio to place `using` statements in the namespace for every new project created using custom project template?

Comment: Why not stick to the pattern that most people use (i.e. using outside of namespace)?

Comment: This one should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: You can edit the template file used to create new class files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface

Comment: I read it already @arcord. The dicussion went in other direction. wheather to keep it inside or outside the namespace. I could not get what I need from that post. In my case, my custom project template should write directives inside the namespace.which is not happening. Some how I should forced VS to do that. I doono how to do that. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @MatthewWatson. This is also not working in my case. This is working when I try to create a class manually. In my case, class in project template is overwritten while creating a new project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[<s>Have you tried</s>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489109/using-directives-be-inside-the-namespace#comment117686316_66572659) You need to setup your preferred placement. You can find this option in the following path:

- Options
- Texteditor
- C#
- Code Style
- change `Preferred 'using' directive placement` to *Inside namespace*

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Thankyou @Christian Gollhardt

Comment: This does not work for me. still generates inside namespace if configured outside