# How to change default c# class template on visual studio for mac

Tags: c#, macos

I used to the window version of visual studio for a long time. i switched to macos recently so i am using visual studio mac(preview 6 and 19 versions) right now. After looong long long searching i could not found how to change default c# template in vs mac.
is there anyone to know?
it is way to much easier in windows as you can see: [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)

Comment: Do you got any solutions for this yet? I'm facing the same problem as well.

Comment: Nope. I switched to Rider. Way too much stabilise.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging for my own project, I have finally found a solution to this

## Solution

---

The location of the template files varies depending on what you would like to edit.

Navigate to:
`/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/Addins`

These files are located in the `AspNet` `AspNetCore` and `Xamarin.Forms.Addin` folders.

For the AspNet modules, these files are located in the `Templates` folder and for Xamarin, you have to navigate to the `Templates` folder and then into either the `iOS`, `Android` or `Core` folders depending on which template files you would like to change.

***Unfortunately I was not able to find where to edit the default files, but I will update this solution as soon as I find them***

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Version: 17.6.7
Navigate to: **/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/Templates**

Then you will find the **.xml** you need to edit