# How do I add a namespace to the default winforms template in visual Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I frequently work with the System.IO namespace. Is there a way to have that be included with each new project I create?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you would need to edit a VS template, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/651055/706456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding it to the *default* template might be tricky, I would leave it alone.

You can easily create an empty project, make all sorts of settings and modifications and save it a s a *new* template (File|Export as template). A lot safer in the long run.

Just make it a habit of starting your new projects from your own custom templates.

If you really want to you can edit the contents of the file that is usually at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\WindowsApplication.zip`

Comment: @mydogisbox - not hard but not something I'd do quickly. You may want to be able to create a 'default' project later.

Comment: If he was changing something significant I would agree, but he wants to add the `System.IO` namespace.  This is a trivial thing to remove.

Comment: Thanks, I dint think about creating my own template. I did look into editing the contents of the WindowsApplication file but I must have made some mistake because Windows Form disappeared completely from the available projects list. luckily I save a backup. My own template IS safer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Changing the default using directives in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve/archive/2007/04/10/changing-the-default-using-directives-in-visual-studio.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is to modify the class.zip file located here (for various options):

Visual Studio 2008

For 64 bit:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

For 32 bit:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip Visual Studio 2010

For 64 bit:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

For 32 bit:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

And then run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` in one of the following locations:

Visual Studio 2008 64-bit

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
```

32-bit

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
```

Visual Studio 2010
64-bit

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\
```

32-bit

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\
```

A more complete answer is [here](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/) and [here](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToEditVSTemplates.aspx).