# Default using statements in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio

I want to add a default using statement to my Xamarin Studio project.  Specifically, instead of the default

```
using System;
```

I want every new file to start with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Can I do that?

EDIT: I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of some help:  [Default using directives in new C# files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651055/default-using-directives-in-new-c-sharp-files)

They are part of the template. You can amend the new class template.  This should be of some help as well:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve/archive/2007/04/10/changing-the-default-using-directives-in-visual-studio.aspx

In case the links die, here is a snippet:  "if you open %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\Class.zip, you can modify the class.cs file within that's used to generate all new C# source files"

Comment: Interesting, on my mac I went hunting and found some xml files at /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/data/options.  However, none of them appear to control the default usings.