# Encapsulate using directive statements C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, using-directives

I have a number of using directives declaring the namespaces I am going to use in multiple classes.
Is there a way to refer multiple using statements via a single using directive or any other approach to this solution that I can implement for all the classes?
The classes/files might or might not be under the same namespace.
Example :

```
//Fil1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace NS1
{
    public class1
    {
    }
}
```

The reason to encapsulate these using statements is because they'll be common among multiple files.

```
//Fil2.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace NotNS1
{
    public class2
    {
    }
}
```

Would prefer if there were some way to just make one using directive call in the class and define all these using statements elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Nope.  Include all of those `using` statements in each file that requires them.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that, but you could [change the default using directives that Visual Studio adds automatically to every file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/651062/2791540) so that all of your using directives are included by default. That could save you a little typing I guess.

Comment: I mean, select usings, Ctrl+C, create new class, select usings, Ctrl+V. I could have created 6 classes using that technique in the time it took to write the question...

Comment: No, `C#` doesn't support `c`-style common header files or macros, something that could have perhaps achieved what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no magic `using` or `#include` like in the C world. You have to be explicit in each file or namespace what you are `using`.

Many tools, including Visual Studio, ReSharper and Rider include tools to help manage `using` directives.

Answer (score -1):

No, but IDEs usually handle imports quite well, but you can place all your classes in a single namespace and import that, even tho thats very bad practice.